# Переключение на активность из FragmentList

Tags: java, android

Мне требуется при нажатии в ListFragment на определенный пункт списка событием `onListItemClick` переключиться на активность. Как это осуществить? Искал в уроках по программированию под андроид, везде приводится приводится пример как вывести `Toast`. За пунктами меню уже закреплены картинка и текст в разметке. Помогите решить мою проблему, буду очень признателен.

Код ListFragment:

```
public class Name_ListFragment extends ListFragment {
String data_name[] = new String[]{"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4",
        "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9", "name10"};

int images[] = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8, R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("keyText", data_name[i]);
        hm.put("keyImage", Integer.toString(images[i]));
        list.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {"keyImage", "keyText"};

    int[] to = {R.id.image1, R.id.text1};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Код разметки list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код в класс Name_ListFragment

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    chooseActivity(position);
}


private void chooseActivity(int position){

   //Мы заранее знаем как расположены пункты меню в адаптере.
   //Зная позицию мы можем понять какое действие выполнить
   switch(position){
       case 0:
          startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Another_Activity.class));
          break;
       case 1:
          startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Another_Activity.class));
          break;
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: В том то и дело что я так пробовал. (this, ActivityNew.class) подчеркивается красным цветом с подписью Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(fragments.Name_ListFragment, java.lang.Class<com.test.test2.test3.ActivityNew>)' И да, я немного переформировал вопрос. Я забыл написать что мне надо при нажатии на определенный пункт списка переключится на активность

Comment: Изменил код, попробуйте снова

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. А чтобы переключится при нажатии на определенный пункт списка(извините что не сразу сформулировал вопрос правильно) на активити как надо действовать?

Comment: В "startActivity(intent)" intent подчеркнуто красным с надписью Variable 'intent' might not have been initialize.

Comment: Дело в том что я не проверял код в IDE, писал сразу в ответ. Отредактировал код ещё разок. Попробуйте ещё разок)